# Determining the fourth vertex of a parallelogram knowing that its the point of intersection of two circles

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

This question was part of the exercises in one of the courses i'm taking. The answer was already provided. The first circle was assumed to have as its center, vector $v_1$, while its radius was the distance between vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$. The second circle was assumed to have as its center, vector $v_3$, while the distance between vector $v_1$ and $v_2$ was its radius. This gave two equations and we solve the equations to get $D$. What I don't understand is why the distance between the vectors is assumed to be the radius. I have an inkling that this has to do with the properties of the parallelogram but i don't really know. Any input would be appreciated.

Question: Find the fourth vertex $D(x,y)$ of the parallelogram determined by the vertices $A(2,1)$, $B(5,3)$, and $C(7,8)$ as a point of intersection of two circles determined by the vectors:
$$
v_1= [2,1]^T, v_2=[5,3]^T, v_3=[7,8]^T
$$

Comment: $D_1$ and $D_2$ are the 2 possible choices of D. Find them first. Then test which one lies on the said circle.

Comment: It would be better to refer to the centers of the circles as *points* rather than vectors, and likewise to refer to the radius of each circle as the distance between *points* rather than the distance between vectors.  Although here points and vectors both have two coordinates, the notion of finding the missing corner of the parallelogram is more clearly expressed as finding a *point* of intersection between two circles.

Answer (score 0):

We see the desired parallelogram in this diagram. (I emphasize the points here rather than the vectors.)

[image]

The relevant property of a parallelogram here is that *opposites sides have the same length*. Therefore, the length of segment $AB$ equals the length of segment $CD$. One way to find point $D$ is to draw the circles with the appropriates radii to guarantee those equal segments, so that means drawing a circle centered at point $A$ with radius $BC$ and a circle centered at $C$ with radius $AB$.

You did not ask for help in solving the two circle equations to find point $D$: ask if you do need that help.

Comment: so, if we were to solve this equation. The equation of the circle with center A would be: 

(x-2)^2+ (y-1)^2= (llBCll)^2

and the circle with center c would be:

(x-7)^2+(y-8)^2 = (llABll)^2.

We then deduce that since d is a point of interection, its coordinates should satisfy both equations and solve the system?

Comment: Yes, that is almost right. You can see in my diagram that there are *two* solutions to those two equations, and only one of them will make a parallelogram. Be aware that this method does solve the problem of finding the parallelogram, but there are other ways that are much easier. However, I stuck to your question and answered that.